# Javascript doesnt seem to pass object by reference

Tags: javascript

```js
function ngOnInit() {
  let ref1 = {
    foo: 'bar'
  };
  let ref2 = ref1;
  ref2 = null;
  console.log(ref1, ref2);
}

ngOnInit();
```

I would expect to see ref1 and ref2 both equal to NULL but they are not. In the console they report

ref1: Object { foo: "bar" }

ref2: null

is this expected?
If so how do I pass by reference?

Comment: You *are* passing it by reference but here you are changing what `ref2` points to. That does not change the state of the assigned instance that `ref1` points to. As a test change the line `ref2 = null;`  to this `ref2.foo = null;`, what does your console display now?

Comment: why was this voted down exactly? i provided code and a good explanation of what was my issue was.

Comment: @Clint there is nothing even slightly related to Angular in this question, only basic JavaScript, nor is there any objects being passed - just references to objects being reassigned; of course you may not have known those things but it does make it (unintentionally) a misleading and poorly-formed question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript by reference vs. by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value)

Comment: There’s a common misconception that Javascript is pass-by-value sometimes and pass-by-reference when dealing with non-primitives. The reality is that Javascript is **always** pass-by-value, only that when dealing with non-primitives the value IS a reference. When you set `ref2` to `null`, you’re simply overwriting its *value*, which has no effect on `ref1`’s *value* nor the object that that *value* just happens to be a reference to.

Comment: @Lennholm Indeed, this misconception is not just for JavaScript but most modern languages - in general "pass by reference" has come to mean "pass by a value which is a reference", see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value) for more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is unrelated to Angular... it's just how JavaScript works. You've overwritten ref2's reference to the object. This does not also overwrite ref1's reference to the object.

Instead, change a property of the object referred to by ref2 and see that the change also happens to the object referred to by ref1... because they both *reference* the same object.

```js
function ngOnInit() {
  let ref1 = {
    foo: 'bar'
  };
  let ref2 = ref1;
  ref2.foo = 'baz';
  console.log(ref1, ref2);
}

ngOnInit();
```

This would result in:

ref1: Object { foo: "baz" }

ref2: Object { foo: "baz" }